# Generating javascript object with array as value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays with data like:

[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1]]

What I want is an object that looks like:
{0: [1,2,3],
1: [1]}

I tried:

```
                var obj = {};

                $.each(List, function(index, value) {
                        obj[value[0]] = value[2];

                    });
```

But it obviously overwrites the previous value for the key. Is there an easy way to add all the values to each unique key (sort of like a dictionary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tests to see if the property exists. If not, it creates it and assigns the Array.

Once the property and array exist, it can push in the value.

```
var obj = {};

$.each(List, function(index, value) {
    if( !obj[value[0]] )
        obj[value[0]] = [];

    obj[value[0]].push(value[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dYz8w/

---

You can avoid a `.push()` call when the Array is created if you do this...

```
var obj = {};

$.each(List, function(index, value) {
    if( !obj[value[0]] )
        obj[value[0]] = [value[1]];
    else
        obj[value[0]].push(value[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dYz8w/1/

---

And keep in mind that if you need to guarantee order of iteration, you should use an Array instead of an Object.

```
var arr = [];

$.each(List, function(index, value) {
    if( !arr[value[0]] )
        arr[value[0]] = [value[1]];
    else
        arr[value[0]].push(value[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dYz8w/3/